# $n\mid5^n - 3^n + 1$. Does it imply liminf of $\nu_3(n)$ to go to infinity?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose $S$ is a set of all positive integers $n$ such that $n\mid5^n-3^n+1$.

For each nonnegative integer $m$ define $S_m$ as $\{n\in S:\nu_3(n)=m\}$, where $\nu_p(n)$ is $p$-adic valuation of $n$ (i.e., the largest $k$ such that $p^k\mid n$). Notice that $3^m\in S_m$, according to [LTE lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma), since $\nu_3(5^{3^m}+1^{3^m})=\nu_3(5+1)+\nu_3(3^m)\geq m$ and $\nu_3(3^{3^m})=3^m\geq m$. In particular, $S$ is infinite.

> Conjecture: $S_m$ is finite for each nonnegative integer $m$.

In other words, if $n\in S$, $n\to\infty$, then $\nu_3(n)\to\infty$. If so, then how to prove it? Or maybe is it beyond our opportunities?

Possible generalizations for ($n\mid a_1^n\pm\ldots\pm a_k^n$, $\;n\to\infty$)-case are highly appreciated. Though, it's tough a bit to find the suitable prime $p$ for $\nu_p(n)\to\infty$. (Again, if it's true). Of course, even showing existence of such $p$ would be really nice, I guess.

Well, if conjecture doesn't hold (although, some numerical data asserts it's highly likely to hold), I'd like to get some bounds on $S_m\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $n\to\infty$.

Here is a list of $T_i=S_i\cap\{1,\ldots,10^5\}$, $i=0,1,2$ and $T_j=S_j\cap\{1,\ldots,10^6\}$, $j=3,4,5,6$:
$T_0=\{1, 143, 391, 583\}$, $T_1=\{3,33\}$, $T_2=\{9, 909, 6381, 7191\}$, $T_3=\{27, 1269, 6453, 607689\}$, $T_4=\{81, 2349, 201771, 265437\}$, $T_5=\{243,2673\}$, $T_6=\{729, 376893\}$.

UPD. Now, thanks to numerical data, provided by Peter, I am able to prove the **conjecture doesn't hold for** $S_0$. I claim that $a_m=11\cdot13\cdot79^{2m}\in S_0$ for each integer $m\geq0$.
Notice that $\mathrm{ord}_{\varphi(143)}(79)=2$. Thus, since $143\mid5^{a_0}-3^{a_0}+1$, we have $143\mid5^{a_m}-3^{a_m}+1$ for all $m>0$. Also notice that $\mathrm{ord}_{79}(5^{143})=\mathrm{ord}_{79}(-3^{143})=3$. We have $\varphi(3)=2$ and $\mu(3)=-1$. Therefore, similarly to [this AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1999000p14258991), we obtain that $79^m\mid\left(5^{143}\right)^{79^m}-\left(3^{143}\right)^{79^m}+1$ for all $m>0$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: It might be obvious to you and/or other people on this site, but is $S$ infinite to begin with? Since you want to take $n$ to infinity. Sorry if that sounds like a silly question.

Comment: @Bruno , I expanded the post with the reason why $S$ is infinite

Comment: Have you tabulated the values of $n$ such that $n$ divides $5^n-3^n+1$? Can you show us the first few?

Comment: You write that $S$ is **a** set such that its elements have a certain property. This would still allow $S$ to be empty

Comment: @GerryMyerson , added them to the post

Comment: $$n=455\ 830\ 689$$ is a large example with $v_3(n)=1$. That makes me sceptical whether the conjecture is actually true since in this case I would rather expect that large examples are only possible if $v_3(n)$ is large. Of course, the conjecture might still be true.

Comment: Another example with valuation $1$ is $$4\ 470\ 840\ 183$$

Comment: And one with valuation $0$ (not divisible by $3$) : $$5\ 569\ 861\ 583$$

Comment: @Peter thanks a lot for provided data. It helped a lot. By the way, do you use some software to compute such things fastly? Or is it just like "10 hours of constant computing"?

Comment: It is relatively efficient (PARI/GP) , but those numbers needed nevertheless 1-2 hours.

Comment: Using a special idea , I found the very large example not divisible by $3$: $$223\ 738\ 362\ 461\ 019\ 188\ 759\ 689\ 277$$